# Display all rows and update all rows by a submit

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli, foreach

I want to display all rows by a php query and update all by a submit button in sql. I this way below a can display all row and update particular row by its own submit button. But I want to update all by a single submit button.

So for do it, I thank, I want to loop for update. But I cannot understand how to do it in this case.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('../db.php');
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ppad");
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['id']; 
    $name=$row['name'];
    $date=$row['date'];
    $title=$row['title'];
    $Detail=$row['Detail'];

echo '<form action="padSproccess.php" method="POST">        
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Date</td>
    <td width="14%">Time</td>
    <td width="20%">Name(url)</td>
    <td width="30%">Detail</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="date" maxlength="2" value="'.$date.'"></td>
    <td width="14%"><input type="text" name="title" maxlength="50" value="'.$title.'"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="50" value="'.$name.'"></td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="Detail" maxlength="100" value="'.$Detail.'"></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$id.'">
    </tr>
</table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';}
?>
```

`padSproccess.php`

```
include("../db.php");
global $db;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['date']);
    $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['title']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['name']);
    $Detail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['Detail']);
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['id']);
    // update data in mysql database 
    $update = mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE ppad SET date='$date', month='$month', name='$name', Detail='$Detail' WHERE id = '$id'"); 

// if successfully updated. 
}
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're experiencing with the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do first is have an overall form, not a form for each (unless you want to throw in javascript to fire off ajax calls). So what you'll need to do is make sure each row can be associated with a specific id:

```
<?php

include_once '../db.php';

$result = mysqli_query($dbh, "SELECT * FROM ppad");

if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

?>

<form action="padSproccess.php" method="POST">
    <table width="100%" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">Date</td>
                <td width="14%">Time</td>
                <td width="20%">Name(url)</td>
                <td width="30%">Detail</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id     = $row['id']; 
                $name   = $row['name'];
                $date   = $row['date'];
                $title  = $row['title'];
                $Detail = $row['Detail'];

                echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="date[' . $id . ']" maxlength="2" value="'.$date.'"></td>
                        <td width="14%"><input type="text" name="title[' . $id . ']" maxlength="50" value="'.$title.'"></td>
                        <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="name[' . $id . ']" maxlength="50" value="'.$name.'"></td>
                        <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="Detail[' . $id . ']" maxlength="100" value="'.$Detail.'"></td>
                    </tr>
                ';
            }

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Then in `padSproccess.php` you'll receive an array of `names`, `dates`, `titles` and `Details`, each one keyed by the `ID` of the row. So that'll change to something like this:

```
<?php

include "../db.php";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $ids = array_keys($_POST['name']);

    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $date   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['date'][$id]);
        $title  = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['title'][$id]);
        $name   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['name'][$id]);
        $Detail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['Detail'][$id]);
        $id     = mysqli_real_escape_string($id);
        // update data in mysql database 
        $update = mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE ppad SET date='$date', month='$month', name='$name', Detail='$Detail' WHERE id = '$id'"); 
    }

// if successfully updated. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to update your code into

```
<?php
include_once('../db.php');
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ppad");
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}?>
<form action="padSproccess.php" method="POST">        
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Date</td>
    <td width="14%">Time</td>
    <td width="20%">Name(url)</td>
    <td width="30%">Detail</td>
</tr>
<?php 
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['id']; 
    $name=$row['name'];
    $date=$row['date'];
    $title=$row['title'];
    $Detail=$row['Detail'];

echo '<tr>
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="date[]" maxlength="2" value="'.$date.'"></td>
    <td width="14%"><input type="text" name="title[]" maxlength="50" value="'.$title.'"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="name[]" maxlength="50" value="'.$name.'"></td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="Detail[]" maxlength="100" value="'.$Detail.'"></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'">
    </tr>';
}?>

</table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now within your `padSproccess.php` you'll receive an array of results within your variables which'll be updated using `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Of course for the database I've not started and it is possible errors.

```
<?php
include_once('../db.php');
global $db;
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ppad");
if(!$result) {
    die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
?>
<form action="padSproccess.php" method="POST">
<?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['id']; 
    $name=$row['name'];
    $date=$row['date'];
    $title=$row['title'];
    $Detail=$row['Detail'];

echo '        
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="10%">Date</td>
    <td width="14%">Time</td>
    <td width="20%">Name(url)</td>
    <td width="30%">Detail</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td width="10%"><input type="text" name="ar['.$id.'][date]" maxlength="2" value="'.$date.'"></td>
    <td width="14%"><input type="text" name="ar['.$id.'][title]" maxlength="50" value="'.$title.'"></td>
    <td width="20%"><input type="text" name="ar['.$id.'][name]" maxlength="50" value="'.$name.'"></td>
    <td width="30%"><input type="text" name="ar['.$id.'][Detail]" maxlength="100" value="'.$Detail.'"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

';}
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php   
include("../db.php");
global $db;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['ar'] as $id=>$dat){
        $date = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$dat['date']);
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$dat['title']);
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$dat['name']);
        $Detail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$dat['Detail']);
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$id]);
        // update data in mysql database 
        $update = mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE ppad SET date='$date', month='$month', name='$name', Detail='$Detail' WHERE id = '$id'"); 
    }
// if successfully updated. 
}
?>
```