# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Tags: php

My form cannot update any data, please help me, Its display error on "array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given" in line 4 and "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in line 5 at ramadan.php.

Here I want to display all data from sql query and update all by another query.

Its work well in my another web page but in this case its cannot work..

my form

```
<form action="ramadan.php" method="POST">
<?
$result = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM ramadan WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)");
if(!$result) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error());
}
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id=$row['id'];
    $ramadan=$row['ramadan'];
    $date=$row['date'];
    $taraweeh=$row['taraweeh'];

echo '
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="ramadan['.$id.']" class="form-control" value="'.$ramadan.'"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="date['.$id.']" class="form-control" value="'.$date.'"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="taraweeh['.$id.']" class="form-control" value="'.$taraweeh.'"></td>
  </tr>
';}
?>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

ramadan.php

```
include("../db.php");
global $dbh;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$ids = array_keys($_POST['name']);
  foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $ramadan = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['ramadan'][$id]);
    $date   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['date'][$id]);
    $taraweeh   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$_POST['taraweeh'][$id]);
    $id     = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$id);
    // update data in mysql database 
    $update = mysqli_query($dbh,"UPDATE ramadan SET hl='$hl', ramadan='$ramadan', date='$date', taraweeh='$taraweeh' WHERE id = '$id'"); 
}  

// if successfully updated. 
}
```

Comment: You are not posting `$_POST['name']` anywhere.

Comment: See this was a question ans of mine which work well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29984790/4453049

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just added `$ids = array_keys($_POST['ramadan']);` at `$ids = array_keys($_POST['name']);` and problem solved...

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong,
the POST will contain arrays of
ramadan
date
taraweeh

```
$_POST['name']
```

will be an array in you have the next inputs in the form

```
<input type="text" name="name[1]"  value="xxx"/>
<input type="text" name="name[2]"  value="yyy"/>
<input type="text" name="name[3]"  value="zzz"/>
<input type="text" name="name[4]"  value="aaa"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = array_keys($_POST['name']);
```

for this input, you need to keep the form element's `name="` in array like Mr.Zion said above. keep names as an array.

```
<input type="text" name="name[1]"  value="xxx"/>
<input type="text" name="name[2]"  value="yyy"/>
<input type="text" name="name[3]"  value="zzz"/>
<input type="text" name="name[4]"  value="aaa"/>
```